# Why $\cap \emptyset \ne \emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $X$ is a collection of sets, define $\bigcap X$ = $\bigcap_{U \in X} U$.  According to this definition,

$$\bigcap \emptyset \ne \emptyset$$

Too see this, note that if $x \notin \bigcap \emptyset$, there exists $U \in \emptyset$ such that $x \notin U$.  However, by definition, that's impossible.

But what set would $\bigcap \emptyset$ be? Everything?

Comment: I think that I wrote that answer at least twice, if not more.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You say this is a duplicate?

Comment: @Babak: Most definitely.

Comment: more like a triplicate

Comment: Here we go: [this is one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/unary-intersection-of-the-empty-set) and [that's another](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348668/intersection-of-the-empty-set-and-vacuous-truth/). And [that is an even more compelling duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370188/empty-intersection-and-empty-union).