# Why is this counterargument not logically valid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If one defines $Z=\cap_{i\in I}\alpha_i = \{x:\forall i\in I, x\in\alpha_i\}$ then apparently if $I = \emptyset$ this definition yields the absolute universe. The proof of this is that if $x\notin Z$ then $\exists i(x\notin \alpha_i)$, which cannot hold, as there is no such $i$, as then $i\in\emptyset$.

I understand this, and I accept that this is a valid argument, but then why is not:

If $x\in Z$ then $\forall i(x\in \alpha_i)$, there are no $i$s as $I=\emptyset$ so there do not exist any sets $\alpha_i$for $x$ to be a member of, so $\forall x(x\notin Z)$

I know both being true is paradoxical, but paradoxes arise with unrestricted comprehension.

Comment: Borderline duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348668/intersection-of-the-empty-set-and-vacuous-truth

Comment: This is even somewhat intuitive. The intersection of sets sits inside each of the original sets. But then the empty intersection is not restricted to sit inside anything at all. Compare that to intersecting with the empty set, which is maximally restricted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with a formal argument.

Assume the definition :

> $Z=\cap_{i \in I} \alpha_i=\{ x : ∀i \in I,x \in α_i \}$.

We know the basic property of the "set-builder" notation : $\{ x : \varphi \}$, i.e. $x \in \{ x : \varphi \} \Leftrightarrow \varphi(x)$.

Thus, we have :

> $x \in Z \Leftrightarrow \forall i (i \in I \Rightarrow x \in α_i)$ --- **(*)**

(I'll prefer to be pedantic and avoid the use of "restricted quantifiers").

The formula **(*)** is a bi-conditional and "it works" like an *axiom*, stating the basic property of the defined symbol $Z$, "naming" the set built-up from the intersection of the "family" of sets : $\alpha_i, i \in I$.

The bi-conditional means also that, every time we have : $\forall i (i \in I \Rightarrow x \in α_i)$, we can derive : $x \in Z$ by *modus ponens*.

---

Now for the proof :

1) $I = \emptyset$ --- assumption : the "index-set" is empty

2) $\forall i (i \notin I)$ --- from 1) by definition of *empty set*

3) $i \notin I$ --- from 2) and the logical axiom : $\forall x \alpha \Rightarrow \alpha^x_t$ by *modus ponens*, where $\alpha^x_t$ is the result of the replacement of the occurrences of the *variable* $x$ in $\alpha$ with the *term* $t$

4) $(i \in I \Rightarrow x \in α_i)$ --- from 3) and the *tautology* : $\lnot p \Rightarrow (p \Rightarrow q)$ by *modus ponens*, where we have $i \in I$ in place of $p$ and $x \in \alpha_i$ in place of $q$

5) $\forall i (i \in I \Rightarrow x \in α_i)$ --- from 4) by *generalization*

6) $x \in Z$ --- from 5) and the axiom **(*)** by *modus ponens*

> 7) $\forall x(x \in Z)$ --- from 6) by *generalization*.

Thus, having assumed the axiom **(*)** corresponding to the definition, we have derived, "by logic alone", that :

> **if** $I= \emptyset$ (i.e. the set $I$ is empty),**then** for all $x$, $x$ belongs to the set $Z=\cap_{i \in I} \alpha_i$.

---

---

Your "counterargument" is something like :

1) assume : $x \in Z \Rightarrow \forall i (i \in I \Rightarrow x \in α_i)$

and try to "contrapose" it, in order to derive $x \notin Z$.

But the negation of the consequent of 1) is :

> $\lnot \forall i (i \in I \Rightarrow x \in α_i)$ i.e. $\exists i (i \in I \land x \notin α_i)$.

Now we assume :

2) $I=\emptyset$, i.e. $\forall i(i \notin I)$, i.e. $\forall i \lnot (i \in I)$.

But from the fact that : for **no** $i$ : $i \in I$, we cannot derive that there is some $i$ such that $i \in I$, and thus we cannot derive : there is some $i$ such that $(i \in I$ and ...) either.

You are saying :

> "$I=\emptyset$, so there do not exist any sets $α_i$ for $x$ to be a member of";

we can formalize it as : $\forall x \lnot \exists i (x \in \alpha_i)$, i.e. : $\forall x \forall i (x \notin \alpha_i)$.

But again, $\forall i (x \notin \alpha_i)$ is **not** the negation of : $\forall i (i \in I \Rightarrow x \in α_i)$, and neither of : $\forall i (x \in α_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

if$x\in Z$ then $$\forall i\in I, x\in\alpha_i$$ which means
 $$\forall i,\ i\in I \Rightarrow x\in\alpha_i$$
 and there is not any contradiction because $i\notin I$; as $I=\emptyset$

maybe truth table can help:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read about [vacuous truths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Suppose we have the implication $\forall x \in A \implies statement$. Then if $A$ is empty, $statement$ is true.