# Unions and Intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Will I be correct in stating the following?

> The intersection of a collection of sets need not be a subset of its union.

This is what I’m thinking while positing the above: $\bigcup \varnothing =\varnothing,$ but $\bigcap \varnothing$ is not even a set.

---

But I think that my proposition will be false for a nonempty collection of sets, correct?

Comment: If $\alpha\in A_n$ for every $n$, is $\alpha\in A_k$ for some $k$?

Comment: You probably mean $\emptyset$ (i.e. the empty set) and not $\phi$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Read the question carefully. I'm talking about empty sets in particular.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Of course.

Comment: It wasn't very clear before the edit.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Edited

Comment: @MarkKamsma Edited

Comment: Still, my first comment is relevant here, and highlights the cases of $\forall x\in\varnothing$ and $\exists x\in\varnothing$.

Comment: You may also wish to see [Wikipedia: Nullary intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)#Nullary_intersection)

Comment: Looking at your profile, you seem to be very bad at giving titles to questions. "*Unions and intersections*" means nothing. "*Are my logical translations correct?*" and "*What does Paul Halmos mean here?*" are also very bad titles. You have 150 characters to use for a title. Please use them. You can use math symbols, and you should when it makes sense. People shouldn't read your question in order to get an idea what your question is *about*, the title should be doing that already (for the most part).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348668/intersection-of-the-empty-set-and-vacuous-truth

Comment: Some books (I think Kunen, but don't have it right now to verify) may suggest the convention that $\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$ just so the operation is defined (for the usual interpretation could lead to $\cap\emptyset=$ the class of all sets, which is not a set). It is only a convention (with the virtue that $\cap A$ is always a well-defined set, for every set $A$).

Answer (score 1):

Facts first:

- If $A\ne \varnothing$, then $\bigcup A$ and $\bigcap A$ are both sets and $\bigcap A\subseteq \bigcup A$.
- If $A =\varnothing$, then $\bigcup A=\varnothing$, and $\bigcap A$ does not exist (as a set).

Whether your statement is a reasonable expression of this state of facts is more a question of language and communication, than one of hard mathematical truth. You certainly have a defensible position that it is *not wrong*. But still it sounds pretty odd, because in order to be *right*, it has to be speaking of "the" intersection of a collection of sets in a situation where there is no such intersection at all.

Other than winning bar bets because the claim tricks the listener into not considering the empty collection, I have doubts that your claim serves a useful communicative purpose, standing alone.

We could imagine uttering that claim while trying to develop an automatic proof verification system, where someone had implemented a rule that $\bigcap A\subseteq \bigcup A$ for general $A$. But then it would be much better communication to actually point at the concrete problem for $A=\varnothing$ than to merely deny that the rule is valid.

In any case, this is not a problem that is specific to set theory. We could get mostly the same discussion out of considering a statement in arithmetics such as

> $\frac 1 x \cdot x$ is not necessarily $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about the subsets of a fixed "universal" set (these form a kind of structure called a *complete atomic Boolean algebra*), then every collection of sets has a union and an intersection, and the intersection is contained in the union, *except* when the collection is empty.

More generally, in a [complete lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice), every set has a supremum and an infimum, and $\inf X\le\sup X$ holds *except* when $X=\emptyset$. For example, every set of real numbers has a supremum and an infimum in the extended real line, and $\inf X\le\sup X$ when $X\ne\emptyset$, but $\sup\emptyset=-\infty$ and $\inf\emptyset=+\infty$.